# How to do "stream" parsing in Boost Spirit X3?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am trying to find out the correct way to parse from an `istream` using x3. Older docs refer to `multi_pass` stuff, can I still use this?  Or is there some other way to buffer streams for X3 so that it can backtrack ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use this. Just include

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
```

Example **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef16cc2aa00e6122)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss("{ 123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789, 900, 1011 }");
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(iss), l;

    std::vector<int> values;

    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    if (x3::phrase_parse(f, l, '{' >> (x3::int_ % ',') >> '}', x3::space, values)) {
        std::cout << "Parse results:\n";
        for (auto v : values) std::cout << v << " ";
    } else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parse results:
123 234 345 456 567 678 789 900 1011
```

Comment: I think in general one needs to `iss.unsetf(std::ios::skipws); // No white space skipping!`. Here it works by accident it seems.